# How to test code that is using whatwg-fetch with mocha?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, fetch

I'm using https://github.com/github/fetch in my app, which works fine but I would like to test my code with Mocha and babel since I'm writing ES2016.

This does not work out of the box. I'm getting:

```
1) testApi.js Test api error handling:
 ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
  at callApi (callApi.js:10:10)
  at Context.<anonymous> (testApi.js:8:40)
```

Because well, fetch is not defined. When I build for the browser fetch is exposed by webpack.

I've tried using https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch but the api is slightly different and wants full url's instead of relative paths for example.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: You want to test your code with Node?

Comment: I don't really care, but I've written all my assertions using Chai and currently running using Mocha. I'm writing ES2016 so somewhere in the pipeline babel needs to transpile it..

Comment: It sounds like you're using a global `fetch` (the one provided by your browser), or webpack globalizes it for you. If you use something like [`isomorphic-fetch`](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) and use a proper `const fetch = require(...)`, you should be able to test both client and server side and have access to `fetch()` on both sides.

Comment: @Tieme did you solve this???

Comment: Nope, I did not..

Answer (score 2):

So, if anyone has this problem in the future:

- Use [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch)
- when using webpack make sure your target is set to 'web'
- `import 'isomorphic-fetch'` in your index.js or otherwise root file
- `import 'isomorphic-fetch'` in whatever test file calls fetch (or root test file if you have one)
- your tests will now use node-fetch and your webpack will now build whatwg-fetch

Comment: you can install isomorphic-fetch and in your package.json, set the command for test to be 'mocha --require isomorphic-fetch'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Mocha tests working with a ternary using `node-fetch` module:

```
// Support server-side fetch for tests.
let fetch = (typeof window === 'undefined')
  ? require('node-fetch')
  : window.fetch
;
```

https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch